# Ajax setting cookies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I have a login form with ajax and I am trying to set cookies if a "remember me" checkbox is checked. I already have code that runs when the user has the "remember me" box checked but the cookies aren't being set. Executing `var_dump($_COOKIE)` outputs `array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }` and it outputs the same thing even after executing secookie().

Login.php

```
<?php
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../inc/inc.all.php');
$username;
$password;
$remember;
$token;

if (!isset($_POST['username'])) {
    echo "Username field must be set!";
    die();
}
$username = $_POST['username'];

if (!isset($_POST['password'])) {
    echo "Password field must be set";
    die();
}
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$remember = $_POST['remember'];

if (!isset($_POST['token'])) {
    echo "There was a problem logging you in securly, Prehaps you are trying to log in from a different window?";
    die();
} else {
    $token = $_POST['token'];
}

// Validate token
if (!isset($token) || $token != $_SESSION['token']) {
    echo "Invalid token: There was a problem logging you in securley, Prehaps you are trying to log in from a different window?";
    die();
}

// Log the user in
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM cs_users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND password = '{$password}'";
$query = $db -> query($sql);
if ($query -> num_rows) {
    list($id) = @array_values($query -> fetch_assoc());
    if ($remember) {
        $expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 180;
        echo $id.'<br>'.$username.'<br>'.$password.'<br>';
        setcookie("id", $id, $expire);
        setcookie("username", $username, $expire);
        setcookie("password", $password, $expire);
        // header("LOCATION:{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    }
    echo true;
} else {
    echo "Invalid username/password";
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not set the cookie on the client side using something like [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)? That way you can set it upon AJAX `.done()`.

Comment: @r3mus I don't want to set the cookies via javascript. Otherwise it would take some extensive work to get the cookies to save (I need to save a password cookie encrypted with password_hash())

Comment: You could perform all of the necessary hashing and such on the php side (you'd have to do that anyway?) And return the result back to jQuery, then pop in the cookie.

Comment: so you mean the condition if ($remember) is executed as true, and (echo $id.'<br>'.$username.'<br>'.$password.'<br>';) is being echoed but setcookie("id", $id, $expire); is not actually creating the cookie in the browser, is that right?

Comment: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: @Quentin I do know that I am using a unsuitable hashing algorithm. It is on my to-do list to switch over to password_hash():

Comment: @MohammedJoraid yes. That is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. It **Was** setting the cookies. For the domain `/internal/cloudshop/login`. Changing the setCookie to `setCookie("username", $username, "/")` fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the session by calling `session_start();`

Comment: The session is already started and works fine. I dealing with COOKIES not SESSION

Comment: Are you sure the session is started in your AJAX script? If you don't use the same includes in your "page" scripts and your "AJAX" scripts it might not be. Is it done in the inc.all.php?

Comment: Yes, it is started in inc.all.php

Answer (score 0):

**Executing var_dump($_COOKIE) outputs array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) 
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" } and it outputs the same thing **even after executing secookie()**.**

**The questions here, can you set another cookies from another scripts? If no means server config issues, else, need to debug current script.**

1. From what I understand from your question, you cannot check test
   `$_COOKIE` from within the same script that set it. In other words,
   you cannot test `var_dump($_COOKIE)` directly after executing
   `secookie()`. You can't read the value of a `$_COOKIE` until a new page request is made. This is because the value of cookie data is sent from the browser with each request.
2. I think setting cookies might take a moment to be settled. The best way to test if you the cookie has been created is to check your browser cookies and see if the cookies are there.
3. When you run the command `setCookie();` it will only take effect when
   the script finishes and pass the output to the browser. Then the
   browser will create the cookie.
4. Check what the return value of setcookie function is maybe it
   returns `FALSE` if output has been already sent before the function
   call.
5. Check PHP configuration and .`htaccess` to see if setting cookies is enabled (try to set cookie regardless if the login process, just set a testing cookie and see if it works).
6. Try adding domain path, setcookie('name','14', time()+3600, '/', 'yourSite.com')
7. Disabling cookies for IP addresses and localhost was a design decision, do you have a domain name?

Hope that helps.

Comment: 1) I am reading it from a different test-page and the cookies are still not there. 2) Chrome says that the cookies set are `PHPSESSID` `ID` `username` from `/cloudshop/internal/ajax/login` `username from `/cloudshp/internal/ajax` `password` from `/cloudshop/internal/ajax` password from `/internal/ajax/login` and `id` from `cloudshop/internal/ajax/login` 4) The `setCookie();` outputs `1` for all of them 5) Cookies set correctly if using [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) 7. I do not have a domain but cookies can be set from `localhost`

Comment: @mrkirby153 it's rather strange. Anyhow, Since you are working on your localhost, does it say in chrome that the cookie is from localhost (Is this your project dir /cloudshop/internal/ajax )? How about creating a new project and and one single script page and just use to set a cookie using the min number of lines and see if it works.